# Rails routing shows :id => nil when trying to show last item in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-routing

My problem is that when I type `http://localhost:3000/builds/1/stories/33` directly in the browser or from any links, I get this error.

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stories", :build_id=>1, :id=>nil}

This seems to only be an issue when I am trying to access the very last item from a table, for example if I were to type 34 as the :id instead, I would get this response.

> Couldn't find Story with id=34 [WHERE "stories"."build_id" = 1]

Which is typically what is expected when the :id doesn't exist. Therefore I am not sure why the error only happens for the last item in a table. Any help would be much appreciated as this is VERY frustrating. Also I am using SQLite3 as my database. When I type 32, the 'show' page is rendered with the appropriate information. I expected this to also happened with 33, since the item does exist in the table, but apparently not.

Here is the return from `rake routes`

> ```
>              /builds/:build_id/stories/:number/:id(.:format) stories#show
> ```
>
> build_stories GET    /builds/:build_id/stories(.:format)             stories#index
>                   POST   /builds/:build_id/stories(.:format)             stories#create
>   new_build_story GET    /builds/:build_id/stories/new(.:format)         stories#new
>   edit_build_story GET    /builds/:build_id/stories/:id/edit(.:format)    stories#edit
>       build_story GET    /builds/:build_id/stories/:id(.:format)         stories#show
>                   PUT    /builds/:build_id/stories/:id(.:format)         stories#update
>                   DELETE /builds/:build_id/stories/:id(.:format)         stories#destroy
>            builds GET    /builds(.:format)                               builds#index
>                   POST   /builds(.:format)                               builds#create
>         new_build GET    /builds/new(.:format)                           builds#new
>        edit_build GET    /builds/:id/edit(.:format)                      builds#edit
>             build GET    /builds/:id(.:format)                           builds#show
>                   PUT    /builds/:id(.:format)                           builds#update
>                   DELETE /builds/:id(.:format)                           builds#destroy
>              root        /                                               builds#index
>              join        /join(.:format)                                 builds#join
>             leave        /leave(.:format)                                builds#leave
>          complete        /complete(.:format)                             builds#complete
>           restart        /restart(.:format)                              builds#restart
>                          /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)              sessions#create
>      auth_failure        /auth/failure(.:format)                         :controller#:action
>           signout        /signout(.:format)                              sessions#destroy

And here is my routes.rb

```
Sapphire::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/builds/:build_id/stories/:number/:id', :to => 'stories#show'
  resources :builds do
    resources :stories
  end
  root :to => "builds#index"
  match '/join', :to => 'builds#join'
  match '/leave', :to => 'builds#leave'
  match '/complete', :to => 'builds#complete'
  match '/restart', :to => 'builds#restart'
  match 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  match 'auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
  match 'signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'signout'
```

Comment: I guess you should paste output of `rake routes` and maybe your `config/routes.rb` content.

Comment: I guess the record is not there related to id 33. Can you share the action section of this controller?